# visual studio 2010 cannot be opened project type () is not supported by this version

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Project was working on PC number 1.  Copied project to external drive and trying to load project from PC number 2.  Both PCs have similar install of VS2010 premium.  Can run the website ok locally.  VS2010 is giving the following error when opening the project.

visual studio 2010 cannot be opened because its project type () is not supported by this version of the application

Error indicates something isn't installed on PC number 2.  But how can I find out what software is missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Visual Web Developer check box was not checked as part of custom Visual Studio install.  Doing an change/repair and ticking that box fixed the issue.  Strange - other web projects loaded fine.  This is the only project that errored.

Answer (score 0):

On the computer where this works, goto:

> Tools > Extensions

This should give you a list of the extensions you have installed and you can cross reference it against the computer where it doesn't work.

I'm guessing you have an MVC project and haven't installed ASP.NET MVC on the second machine.

Comment: Have installed additional extensions (except Enterprise Library v5 Configuration Editor) and still getting the error.  Definitely not an MVC project.

Comment: Did you have a service pack on the first machine? I think VS2010 had a "Service Pack 1" release.